# App.config settings, environment variable as partial path

Tags: c#, xml, windows, app-config, environment-variables

I'm new to tinkering with app.config and xml, and am currently doing some refactoring in some code I haven't written.
Currently we have a snippet which looks like this:

```
<setting name="FirstSetting" serializeAs="String">
  <value>Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\ApplicationData\Company ...;Persist Security Info=False</value>
```

What I'd like to do is have it instead point to something like `${PROGRAMDATA}\Company\...`

How can I achieve this, keeping in mind that PROGRAMDATA will not always point to `C:\ProgramData` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't really want to change it in code as per the other responses, since that removes the purpose of having it as a config setting.

As it turns out, `%ProgramData%\Company...`  is the proper way of using environment variables in this context.

Comment: Just to clarify this is under C:\ProgramData not somewhere under C:\Users (Win7)

Comment: That's right, it results in C:\ProgramData\Company. The issue we had here was that sometimes that directory is on a different drive, so using the environment variable is cleaner and always maps correctly.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(stringFromConfig);
```

it replaces all existing environment variables in the string like %ProgramData% with the exact values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, write it just like that in your setting.  Then just substitute ${PROGRAMDATA} at runtime:

```
        var setting = Properties.Settings.Default.FirstSetting;
        setting = setting.Replace("${PROGRAMDATA)", 
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData));
```

Comment: If you do write code to do this, don't introduce another syntax for environment variables and then try and expand them yourself. Use the (Windows) standrd %NAME% format, and then you can simply call [System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) on the string to do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the `PROGRAMDATA` is an environment variable, you can access using C#

```
String EnviromentPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMDATA", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
var programDataValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMDATA");
```

if it comes from an environment variable.