# environment variable as partial path in app.config

Tags: c#, environment-variables, app-config

I have an environment variable that points to a folder where development code is located. On my machine it is C:\SOME_NAME\CODE. This environment variable is referenced in code, as other computers using the same code have a different path for the same environment variable. I cannot be sure of directory or drive names or even number of levels. I am trying to use relative path in an app.config, but I was unable to get it to work.

```
<setting name="manifestpath" serializeAs="String">
   <value>$(CODE_BASE)\PROJECT\manifest\manifest.xml</value>
</setting>
```

When I run it, I get an error `"Could not find a part of the path C:\SOME_NAME\CODE\PROJECT\output\x64\Debug\$(CODE_BASE)\PROJECT\manifest\manifest.xml".`

I am aware that the exact question has been asked here:
[App.config settings, environment variable as partial path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303113/app-config-settings-environment-variable-as-partial-path).
Unfortunately, I was unable to find an answer that works, I have tried to use % (but my env var doesn't have % in name, and I can't change it because the change would affect lots of other projects and people). Help ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mis-read the answer to the other question.  Your environment variable will never have % in its name.  You surround the variable name with % to signify that it is an environment variable.  So, if you variable is called CODE_BASE, then the following should work:

```
    <value>%CODE_BASE%\PROJECT\manifest\manifest.xml</value>
```

Comment: When I did that, the error I got was "Could not find a part of the path C:\SOME_NAME\CODE\PROJECT\output\x64\Debug\%CODE_BASE%\PROJECT\manifest\manifest.xml". That is why I thought I misread it... or something... because it simply doesn't work.

Comment: That's good. Now you just gotta run this string through [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx](`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`) and you're set.